# Beautiful Soup not returing data within a table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I want to Retrieve a financial dataset from a Website which has a log in. I've managed to log in using requests and access the HTML

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 
s = requests.session()
login_data = dict(email='my login', password='password')
s.post('*portal webiste with/login*', data=login_data)
r = s.get(' *website with finacial page* ')
print (r.content)
## work on r as its a direct link 
 
url = r # stock url
page = url
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text) # returns the htm of the finance page.
```

*The above code allows me to log in and get the html from the correct page.*

```
headers = []
# finds all the headers.
for i in table.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

print(df)
```

this block finds the table and gets the column headers.

which are printed as:

```
Columns: [Date, Type, Type, Credit, Debit, Outstanding, Case File, ]
```

The next part is the problem. when I attempt to retrieve the financials using the following code:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [td.text.strip()for td in data]
    print(row_data)
```

it returns this

```
['"Loading Please Wait..."']
```

HTML of the site looks like this
[html of the site i want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYuCU.png)

Comment: You're trying to scrape a website with a dynamic data source, meaning the data is not actually in the HTML but fetched later on.

Comment: You are most likely dealing with a dynamically generated page. BS cannot handle them.

Comment: Based on the data you did recover, they're likely loading that data after page load, which means that this way won't work. Look into Selenium so you can execute the JS that fetches that data.

Comment: Yup, the fact that you can see the word `ajax` in several places in your screenshot should have been a give-away ;)

Comment: Can you share the URL of  financial page !

Comment: After going through comments, for dynamical pages, better option would be to use Selenium tool to scrape.